# Entry module not found

Tags: babel-loader, babel-jest, babel-polyfill, webpack.config.js

> ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed: 
>     Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/MarkPierre/Desktop/es6-project-2019/src/index.html' in '/Users/MarkPierre/Desktop/es6-project-2019': 
>     Error: Can't resolve '/Users/MarkPierre/Desktop/es6-project-2019/src/index.html' in '/Users/MarkPierre/Desktop/es6-project-2019'

When I run the command `npm run start`, I get the error message mentioned above. 
I've checked the path and it's there. Any ideas?

Seems like the issue occurs with `template: './starter/src/index.html'`. I've removed the `starter`, but still the same issue. Very frustrating as this is the final part of the config :-(

#### babelrc file

```js
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "targets": {
                "browsers": [
                    "last 5 versions",
                    "ie >= 8"
                ]
            }
        }]
    ]
}
```

#### package.json

```js
{
    "name": "forkify",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "forkify project",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack: --mode development",
        "build": "webpack --mode production",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5"
    }
}
```

#### webpack

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './starter/src/js/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        }]
    }

};
```